# How to keep related Partial page/HtmlHelpers, scripts and css together and not separate references

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form that has a button next to *person* textbox that brings up a *person* Bootstrap Modal Search Window.

the html I put in a partial page and reference it

```
   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PersonControlPartialHtml","PersonControl1");}

   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PersonControlPartialHtml","PersonControl2");}
```

which adds a textbox and button.

Then I add a bootstrap modal html to the page that only has to appear once per page

```
   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_PersonControlModal");}
```

Then the javascript event code and css for the above.

```
@section Header {
    <script src="~/css/personcontrolscript.css"></script>
}
```

and

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/personcontrolscript.js"></script>
 }
```

The html I could put in an htmlhelper but I still need to add 3 references to the page if I want to add it to a page.

Is there not an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to reduce this but those ways come with trade offs.  So it really depends on which approach best fits your needs.

So for example you could eliminate adding the .css reference in the header section via two different approaches:

1) you could place those styles in a global.css file that is already loaded for ever page; or 
2) you could use inline styles on you html and eliminate these css classes.

Both of these solutions of course have downsides.  Approach one means that the size of the global.css styles will be larger and take a bit more time to load even if the first page used on the site doesn't need them.  Approach 2 seems to fly in the face of conventional wisdom that you should almost never use inline styles and it will make the markup more verbose. But either solution would allow you to eliminate the need for including a seperate `~/css/personcontrolscript.css` reference every time you have a person control on the page.

As for the need to include ~/js/personcontrolscript.js, that could be solved one of two ways:
1) include the javascript code in a global.js file that is loaded for every page; or 
2) put that javascript code inline in the _PersonControlPartialHtml and add code to it to make sure that it only gets injected the first time the partial is used on the page.

As for the bootstrapModel, I'm a little less clear on what that code looks like so I can't say for sure but probably it could leverage an approach similar to one mentioned for css or js.

With regard to rendering your partials, I don't think there is any way to eliminate that given that it's the primary representation of the functionality you are adding to the page.